# How do I only count visible rows when using the COUNTIFS function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I've been using Excel's COUNTIFS function to count the number of rows in a table that meet certain criteria, E.g:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Result],"Fail", Table1[Comments], "")
```

Now I want to modify this expression so that it only counts rows in Table1 that are visible. (I.E. Not filtered out.) How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple way is to add another column to table - e.g. called `helper` with a formula like this

`=SUBTOTAL(103, B2)`

where column B is Result column

Now change formula to

`=COUNTIFS(Table1[Result],"Fail", Table1[Comments], "",Table1[Helper],1)`

the subtotal formula only returns 1 on visible rows

Without a helper column you can use this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Result]="Fail")*(Table1[Comments]=""),SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(Table1[Result],ROW(Table1[Result])-MIN(ROW(Table1[Result])),0,1,1)))`

Comment: That seems to work. Unfortunately, it's also triggering a weird bug in Excel that's making it very difficult to filter the table: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/filter-bug-in-excel-2007/2364f944-18fa-482d-a1ac-db7464be0894

Do you know of any other way of checking for visible rows that I might be able to use to work around this bug?

Comment: there is a way without helper column - I'll edit my answer in 30 mins, currently on the train (!)

Comment: [this](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/03/19/number-the-visible-rows-in-excel-autofilter/) explains the problem and the fix - change the `SUBTOTAL` formula to `=--SUBTOTAL(103, B2)`

Comment: +1 Sean, never seen that before. Looks like it's sorted but I posted the formula as promised - that should work without need for a helper column

Answer (score 2):

I use this formula:
=subtotal(3,B2:B100)
where subtotal(3, that is  CountA and
B2:b100 is the range.
The hidden rows in a filter are ignored and this formula only counts the visible rows.
It works for me and hope it works for you