# Count the values for a string if the rows are hidden

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to count where:

- column A contains "a"
- the rows containing "a" are hidden.

For example:

If rows 2 & 5 (containing "a") are hidden the output should be 2 (excluding the visible "a" in row 3).

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I only count visible rows when using the COUNTIFS function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323194/how-do-i-only-count-visible-rows-when-using-the-countifs-function)

Comment: @mehow I want to count rows which are not visible.

Comment: Could you please verify whether it's only the visible you want to count or the hidden rows you want to count? As `ColA` also contains an `A` and both situations end up with `2` as result.

Comment: @t.thielemans read the above comment or the title of the question.

Comment: downvoters : Its always a good idea to leave a comment when you downvote so that if there is anything which i missed i should come to know.

Comment: @Santosh, you can also just say you want to count the visible or hidden, or supply data that doesn't cause mixups.

Comment: @t.thielemans What does the title of question say 'Count the values for a string if the rows are hidden' . Is that not sufficient.

Comment: @Santosh, it's ambiguous .. ;) Also your sample doesn't provide clarity as both hidden and visible contain 2. But glad I was right in the beginning :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a healthy portion from [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/145348-how-to-combine-the-subtotal%28%29-and-countif%28%29-functions-in-excel-filter)

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"a")-SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$5="a"),SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)-ROW(A1),0)))
```

Comment: + 1  For a Non VBA Solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This will only count the hidden rows.

```
Sub SumInvisible()

    For i = 1 To 10
        If Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            If Range("A" & i).value = "a" then
                Var = Var + 1
            End if
        End If
    Next i

    Range("B" & i).Value = Var

End Sub
```

Comment: This one is perfect but its my last weapon.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

1) Add a helper column

`=SUBTOTAL(103, A2)`  next to column A, for A3, it becomes (103,A3) and so on

2) Then use

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A5,"a",B2:B5,"=0")`

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, I have a custom function as follows:

```
Public Function IsCellHidden(vRange As Range) As Boolean
    'Check if a cell is hidden

    Dim vHidden As Boolean

    If vRange.Rows(1).Hidden Or vRange.Columns(1).Hidden Then vHidden = True

    IsCellHidden = vHidden
End Function
```

Then I put this into column B on the corresponding cell in column A, so B1 would for instance be `=IsCellHidden(A1)` and then in C6 I would have `=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"A",B1:B10,TRUE)`