# How do I only count visible (filtered) rows when using the COUNTIFS function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I only count visible rows when using the COUNTIFS function?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Table3[Test Point Name],I4),"OK","Missing")
```

I tried to use [How do I only count visible rows when using the COUNTIFS function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323194/how-do-i-only-count-visible-rows-when-using-the-countifs-function) but it jus doesnt work for me i might be doing something wrong.

Comment: What doesn't work for you in that question? Its literally the exact same question.

Comment: When I added,    Table3[Helper],1)  It came up with errors that din't tell me much. " You have entered too many arguments" and it highlights the Table3[Helper]

Comment: `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` are different functions.

Comment: :) Thanks, I'am so bad :(