# How do I only count visible rows when using the COUNTIFS ,COUNTIF, and SUMIF formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been using Excel's COUNTIFS function to count the number of rows in a table, but I'm not sure how to change my formulas to only count from my tables when using filters.

Here are the formulas that I am currently using.

=COUNTIF(USSW1!V7:V10000,110)+COUNTIF(USSW2!V7:V10000,110)-AB6

=+SUMIF(USSW1!$V7:$V10000,"110",USSW1!O7:O10000)-SUMIFS(USSW1!O7:O10000,USSW1!M7:M10000,"FP",USSW1!V7:V10000,"110")

=COUNTIFS(USSW1!V7:V10000,"109",USSW1!M7:M10000,"FP")+COUNTIFS(USSW2!V7:V10000,"109",USSW2!M7:M10000,"FP")

=+SUMIF(USSW1!$V7:$V10000,"110",USSW1!O7:O10000)-SUMIFS(USSW1!O7:O10000,USSW1!M7:M10000,"CA",USSW1!V7:V10000,"110")-SUMIFS(USSW1!O7:O10000,USSW1!M7:M10000,"CF",USSW1!V7:V10000,"110")

=SUMIF(USSW1!$V7:$V10000,"110",USSW1!O7:O10000)

Comment: You're re-using identical ranges a lot - you can greatly simplify your formulas if you give `USSW1!V7:V10000` [a name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I only count visible rows when using the COUNTIFS function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323194/how-do-i-only-count-visible-rows-when-using-the-countifs-function)

Comment: These formulas calculate different numbers from my other excel sheet. I just want to know if there is a way to just get the data that shows up when you filter a table.

Comment: Use the control or criteria that you filter with.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining incorrectly. I'm trying to understand how I can only use countif or any of the others to calculate only visible rows when I filter data from my table.

Comment: When you do `=SUMIF(A2:A11,5,B2:B11)` and there are 2 cells in `A2:A11` equal to 5, and all the cells in `B2:B11` are equal to `10`, the result will be `20`. If you would filter the table in column `A` by the number `5`, there would be 2 cells visible per column. So to get the **sum** (not the SUMIF) of the 2 visible cells in column `B`, you could use `=SUBTOTAL(109,B2:B11)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to `SUMPRODUCT` in such cases. An example would be:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(MyCol1="X"),N(MyCol2="Y"),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(MyCol1,1),ROW(MyCol1)-MIN(ROW(MyCol1)),)))`

which is counting how many visible rows there are for which the entry in *MyCol1* is "X" and the entry in *MyCol2* is "Y".